# Change row color causes error on selection

Tags: jquery, html

Please
I'm using jqgrid!!
I'm having trouble in the table by using the frozen, the function fuinciona the usual problem that the table is transparent and then you can see the content "scraping" below the frozen columns, then looked for a way to change the line to a solid color but this caused me another problem, all opação selection and click stop, does not change color "hover" or "onlick"

COD EXEMPLE:

```
loadComplete : function() {
var table = this;
$("tr.jqgrow:odd").css("background", "#FFFFFF");
$("tr.jqgrow:even").css("background", "#FFFFFF");
```

Removing this code works as usual

Sorry for anything it's my first contact

Comment: Why you need jquery when you can do this with CSS alone?

Comment: Actually, I was desperate and even setting the background with css background is transparent, I will try to show a photo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript to select and style odd or even table rows.

**CSS**

```
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Courtesy of [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css3-zebra-striping-a-table/)

Comment: Almost everything right, even when I select it paints the normal line when he paints odd when I select the entire table, cabelho, navbars, menus.
but thank you anyway, so the selection is still working! 
Thank you! ^^